# Text with solid shadow in React-Native

Tags: android, css, react-native, text, shadow

I am working on an application and trying to achieve solid shadow (as per the design Requirement) in React-Native, that look like in the below image.

[image]

**NOTE: I can not use image as this is a multilingual application.**

What did i try.

I tried to add shadow on the text background but that look like this:-

**style code:**

```
{
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    textShadowRadius: 5,
    fontWeight:'bold',
}
```

[image]

then i tried borderWidth, it also did not work, that works on the component border.

**style code:**

```
{
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    textShadowRadius: 5,
    fontWeight:'bold', 
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'white'
}
```

[image]

Both did not work for me. No one is even closer to the design. Is there any solution for the same?
Or it can not be achieved in React-Native.

Answer (score 0):

I found only 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. Difficult - convert font to SVG and just use letters or words whith svg params or Use Canvas
2. Easy - Wrap word to View and add duplicates with position absolute

```
<View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
  <TextWithShadow style={{position:'relative'}}>Word</TextWithShadow>
  <TextWithShadow style={{position:'absolute'}}>Word</TextWithShadow>
  <TextWithShadow style={{position:'absolute'}}>Word</TextWithShadow>
<View>
```

[Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y1Ki.png)

This way help get more dense shadow. More iterations - more density